# Cheap ARM-based smartbooks: next big thing or another Sony eVilla?

Tags: netbook

If they really can get smartbooks--i.e., smartphone processing and power consumption with a netbook keyboard and display--down to $100/ea, I think it would be perfect for our company.  It'd be great if instead of shared desktops everyone could hit our simple web app from their own small portable device that just needs charging overnight.

However, I hear conspiracy theories (MS shutting such trends down where it can) and nay-sayers (these are just like eVillas, they were useless a decade ago and their modern reincarnations will be just as useless today) that make me wonder if they'll ever actually come to market.  They do seem to be taking their sweet time for such a simple product idea.

Should we be waiting just a little longer, or are smartbooks going to die before they hit the market for whatever reason?

Comment: from the faq "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered! "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get to find anything like that at that price point.  Look at the price of the current e-book readers [here](http://technologizer.com/2009/12/06/nook-review/) -- scroll down towards the bottom for the comparison.  Also look what happened to the supposed low cost tablet [here](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/09/12/07/2046242/CrunchPad-Being-Re-branded-As-JooJoo?art_pos=1) -- no longer is it anywhere near the 200$ price point.  The [litl](http://litl.com/) which looks pretty cool is for some reason 700$.  A decent iPod doesn't even get to 100$.

Top things off with the price of the OLPC still, and it is pretty clear that it will be a good long while before something useful comes out at the price around 100$.